# How to hide Wordpress widget ID programmatically

Tags: php, wordpress

Based on a particular value(appID) I want to hide one of the widget ID in my wordpress blog.

my widget Id : **custom_html-2**  ( I got this value from enabling accessibility mode) 
( from this url I got widgetID : `/wp-admin/widgets.php?widgets-access=on&_wpnonce=0b123456fb2&editwidget=custom_html-2&sidebar=right-sidebar&key=0` )

Here I want to hide **custom_html-2**  when the value of appID is **in.abcd.app** .

I just **echoed appID** , I am getting the value **in.abcd.app** , but the widget is not getting hidden.

I opened the Sidebar (sidebar.php) in the word press and did modification as bellow. Didnt workout - I am new to wordpress and PHP

```
<!-- Sidebar -->
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">

    <aside class="sidebar">

        <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'right-sidebar' ) ) : ?>
        <div class="sidebar-widget">

            <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'right-sidebar' ); ?>

            <?php   
                <?php $widgets  = get_option('widget'.sidebar-widget); ?>
                $appID =  $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] 
                if ($appID = 'in.abcd.app')
                {
                <?php unset($widgets['custom_html-2']); ?>
            ?>


        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

    </aside>

</div>
<!-- /end sidebar -->
```

Comment: You are rendering the widgets before removing them. Also, the best pratice is using wordpress filters and actions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to add something like the following to your functions.php

```
add_filter( 'sidebars_widgets', 'unset_sidebar_widget' );

function unset_sidebar_widget( $sidebars_widgets ) {
    $appID =  $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'];
    if ($appID = 'in.abcd.app')
    {
        unset($sidebars_widgets['custom_html-2']); 
    }
  return $sidebars_widgets;
}
```

Comment: Instead of unset($sidebars_widgets['custom_html-2']);  I gave as 
$sidebars_widgets['right-sidebar'][2] = false;
Got worked ... Thanks @Clayton Leis

Answer (score 1):

I suppose `dynamic_sidebar( 'right-sidebar' );` renders the sidebar and the widgets, so if you unset a widget after the widget was rendered, it's not going to change anything.

Try to put the `dynamic_sidebar( 'right-sidebar' );` after the unset part.